# MinGW (x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc not found)

Tags: mingw

A make file I got is trying to use

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
```

but my system can't find it. Please see picture below.

[image]

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe is not in **C:\MinGW\bin** where I expected to find it (although that directory does have gcc.exe and others).

For reference, I used the "Download Installer" link from http://www.mingw.org/ to install MinGW. I'm on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

Where/how am I supposed to get x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ?

Comment: Try to install `MinGW-w64`, a different version of MinGW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` is part of the MinGW-w64 project. This is different to the MinGW project. So you installed the wrong thing.

[Here is the homepage for MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org). For a self-installer, follow the "Mingw-builds" link from the download page.

Comment: I keep getting an error during installation

Comment: @Jab that's not a very useful problem description. You could post a new question or submit a support ticket

Answer (score 19):

There are three main versions of the MingW:

1- mingw32-gcc.exe
   the compiler will build 32-bit applications on 32-bit systems.

2- i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
   the compiler will build 32-bit applications on 64-bit systems.

3- x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe 
   the compiler will build 64-bit applications on 64-bit systems.

of course, more details arise once you read the documentation. 
ensure you are installing the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened to me, when i build rust compiler.
at windows command console,

solved it by run "msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64".

```
C:\msys64>type run.cmd
msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64
```

From rust github README page:

> Run mingw32_shell.bat or mingw64_shell.bat from wherever you installed
> MSYS2 (i.e. C:\msys64), depending on whether you want 32-bit or 64-bit
> Rust. (**As of the latest version of MSYS2 you have to run**
> **msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32 or msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64 from the command**
> **line instead**)