SDL2 codeblocks unable to find lSDL2_image and lSDL2_ttf
I'm using codeblocks version 20.03 on my Windows 11 pc to compile c++ files, whenever I try to build the file, I get an error that it is unable to find -lSDL2_image and -lSDL2_ttf.
Here are the links to the: SDL_image files https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/tree/SDL2/mingw/pkg-support and the SDL_ttf files https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/releases/tag/release-2.22.0
This is the error message I get in the build messages section
||=== Build: Debug in Tempus (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lSDL2_image|
ld.exe||cannot find -lSDL2_ttf|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

These are the lines of error from the build log
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2_image
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2_ttf
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Edit one:
Here is the full build log
-------------- Build: Debug in Tempus (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -LC:\mingw\lib -o bin\Debug\Tempus.exe obj\Debug\assets.o
obj\Debug\attack_pattern.o obj\Debug\entity.o obj\Debug\game.o
obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\menu.o obj\Debug\particle_system.o
obj\Debug\text_line.o obj\Debug\tools.o obj\Debug\vector.o -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf  
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2_image
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\mingw\lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\mingw\lib/libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\mingw\lib\libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib/libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib\libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../..\libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\mingw\lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\mingw\lib/libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib/libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../libSDL2_ttf.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../libSDL2_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL2_ttf
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2_ttf
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))


The MinGW lib and bin folders have the correct files in them so I'm not too sure why I am getting these errors. if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin contains the files from the SDL bin folders
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib contains the files from the SDL lib folders
I added their cmakes and package-configs to
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\cmake and
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\pkgconfig respectively
Hope that helps

I imagine you're trying to link 32 bit libraries into a 64 bit executable or visa versa

Yes skipping incompatible C:\mingw\lib/libSDL2_ttf.dll.a likely means you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. Your linker says it can't use the .a file because its not compatible with your current build. My guess is the libraries in C:\mingw\lib are 32 bit because x86_64-w64-mingw32 is the 64 bit compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805718/487892

I have the correct files installed now and am no longer getting any of the error messages, thank you for the help.
